# Devise authentication to maintain existing session data

Tags: session, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

An application allows a user to conduct various operations which generate session data.  Then the user may want to execute a transaction based on that data.  A login or sign-up is necessary.

Unfortunately, the session controller in Devise creates a new session, throwing away all that data.  I have not found a concise technique that allows to maintain the existing session data, as this is preferred to writing data to the cookie.

`after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` only allows the user to return to a previous page

Context rails 3.2.18, devise 2.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the session controller is possible. Given that this context has 2 contextually different entry points (generic_url vs confirm_transaction_url), the following various param settings can be carried over and the user brought back to the previous page s/he was on

```
class SessionsController < Devise::RegistrationsController  

  def destroy
    param1       = session[:param1] unless     session[:param1].nil?
    param2       = session[:param2] unless     session[:param2].nil?
    confirm_url  = session[:confirm_url] unless  session[:confirm_url].nil?
    previous_url = session[:previous_url] unless session[:previous_url].nil?
    super  
    session[:param1] = param1
    session[:param2] = param2
    session[:confirm_url]  = confirm_url
    session[:previous_url] = previous_url
  end
end
```

The applications controller will route the user

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || session[:confirm_url]
end
```

*Answer posted for indexing purposes. Thanks to pointer from [onemanarmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/805003/onemanarmy)*